# In app purchases using a tableView cell to segue to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, tableview, storekit

I am trying to write some code so that each cell in my tableView is linked to a different purchase and segues to a different viewController depending on which cell is pressed. If the user has not paid then the segue should not run. I also want to be able to remember that the user has paid for next time so that they will not be asked to pay again.

Another problem I keep running in to is that elsewhere in my app, I have successfully implemented a 'remove ads' function but find that when I test it and purchase a cell in my viewController, the ads are also purchased at the same time. I think the issue lies in the fact that my products request calls 'response.products'. Is there anyway to make this more specific?
My code is below:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class MealPlanViewController: UITableViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    

    
    //MARK: - Purchase methods
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.nutritionModels = response.products
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        
        
        transactions.forEach({
           switch $0.transactionState {
                
           case .purchasing:
            print("purchasing")
           case .purchased:
            
          

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)
           case .failed:
            
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Payment unsuccessful!", message: "You have not been able to purchase this meal plan", preferredStyle: .alert)
                   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                   alert.addAction(action)
                   present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)
           case .restored:
            break
           case .deferred:
            break
           @unknown default:
            break
           }
        })
    }
    
 
    
   
    
    //MARK: - Products
    // To add more products just add to enum
    enum Product: String, CaseIterable {
        case pineappleChicken = "com.pandemicprojects.TFD.pineapplechicken"
        case cauliflowerFriedRice = "com.pandemicprojects.TFD.cauliflowerfriedrice"
        
    }
    
    private func fetchProducts() {
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(Product.allCases.compactMap({$0.rawValue})))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    private var nutritionModels = [SKProduct]()
    
    let mealPlans = MealPlanCollection()
    var numberInArray: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.rowHeight = 80.0
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        fetchProducts()
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return nutritionModels.count
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let product = nutritionModels[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealPlanCell", for: indexPath)
        
  
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(product.localizedTitle) - \(product.priceLocale.currencySymbol ?? "£")\(product.price)"
       
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        numberInArray = indexPath.row
        
        let payment = SKPayment(product: nutritionModels[indexPath.row])
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        

        

    }
    
    


    
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using [Swifty Store Kit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) to manage your application's In App Purchases. It will significantly simplify your transaction logic.

Comment: You don't seem to have any code in the `.purchased` switch state - This is where you need to persist the purchase of the relevant product.